# How to create closable TabItem of TabControl (custom control)?

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol

My English skill is poor because I'm not a native English speaker.
I hope you to understand.

I would like to create tab control that has a closable functionality. (ClosableTabControl)

ClosableTabControl has to has functionality that close tab item when clicked a close button.
Also, I would like to remove ItemsSource related to the closed tab item automatically.

As a result, I want to use the ClosableTabControl in the external project as below.

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DocumentViewModel> Documents {get;}
    ...
}

class DocumentViewModel
{
    public string Title {get;}
    public object Content {get;}
}

<Window DataContext="MainViewModel">
    <ClosableTabControl ItemsSource="Documents"
                        HeaderBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
</Window>
```

As you can see, it does not need to connect a close command to remove Documents in the external project.
Also, it does not need to override the ItemTemplate to binding. (it would solve using HeaderBinding functionality)
I think the above custom control gives the convenience to the external project.

I tried to create like the above control but I faced the problem like below.

***1. It can't remove the element of ItemsSource of the ClosableTabControl. (It need when closed the tab item)***

***2. I don't know how to implement HeaderBinding functionality.***

What I should do to solve the above problem?
I hope your help.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Close Button in tab of Dynamic WPF Tab control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449451/how-to-add-close-button-in-tab-of-dynamic-wpf-tab-control)

Comment: You need to show the implementation otherwise nobody can tell why the removal of items doesn't work. Also don't remove the items from the `ItemsSource` but set the `TabItem.Visibility` to `Visibility.Collapsed`. The control shouldn't mess with the data. It's also easier to e.g. implement "reopen recently closed" behavior.

Comment: Oh that is good idea.
I will think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick and simple example extends `TabControl` and also overrides the default `Style` of `TabControl`. The new `Style` has to be placed inside the *"/Themes/Generic.xaml"* file. The `Style` overrides the default `TabItem` `ControlTemplate` and adds a close button to it.

The `Button.Command` is bound to the Routed Command `CloseTabRoutedCommand` of the `ClosableTabControl`.
Once invoked, the `ClosableTabControl` checks whether the `Items` collection is populated via data binding or e.g. XAML.

If `TabItem` is created via the `ItemsSource` (binding) then the `ICommand` property `ClosableTabControl.RemoveItemCommand` will be executed in order to let the view model remove the item from the collection. This is to avoid to items from the `ItemsSource` directly, which would destroy the binding on this property. The parameter passed to the command delegate is the tab item's data model (in your case of type `DocumentViewModel`) which is requested to remove.
If the `TabItem` is created via XAML, then the item is directly removed without the requirement of the command from the view model.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
class MainViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<DocumentViewModel> Documents {get;}

  // The remove command which is bound to the ClosableTabControl RemoveItemCommand property. 
  // In case the TabControl.ItemsSource is data bound,
  // this command will be invoked to remove the tab item
  public ICommand RemoveTabItemCommand => new AsyncRelayCommand<DocumentViewModel>(item => this.Documents.Remove(item));
    ...
}
```

**ClosableTabControl.cs**

```
public class ClosableTabControl : TabControl
{
  public static readonly RoutedUICommand CloseTabRoutedCommand = new RoutedUICommand(
    "Close TabItem and remove item from ItemsSource", 
    nameof(ClosableTabControl.CloseTabRoutedCommand), 
    typeof(ClosableTabControl));

  // Bind this property to a ICommand implementation of the view model
  public static readonly DependencyProperty RemoveItemCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "RemoveItemCommand",
    typeof(ICommand),
    typeof(ClosableTabControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

  public ICommand RemoveItemCommand 
  { 
    get => (ICommand) GetValue(ClosableTabControl.RemoveItemCommandProperty); 
    set => SetValue(ClosableTabControl.RemoveItemCommandProperty, value); 
  }

  static ClosableTabControl()
  {
    // Override the default style. 
    // The new Style must be located in the "/Themes/Generic.xaml" ResourceDictionary
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ClosableTabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ClosableTabControl)));
  }

  public ClosableTabControl()
  {
    this.CommandBindings.Add(
      new CommandBinding(ClosableTabControl.CloseTabRoutedCommand, ExecuteRemoveTab, CanExecuteRemoveTab));
  }

  private void CanExecuteRemoveTab(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    e.CanExecute = e.OriginalSource is FrameworkElement frameworkElement 
                   && this.Items.Contains(frameworkElement.DataContext)
                   || this.Items.Contains(e.Source);
  }

  private void ExecuteRemoveTab(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.ItemsSource == null)
    {
      object tabItemToRemove = e.Source;
      this.Items.Remove(tabItemToRemove);
    }
    else
    {
      object tabItemToRemove = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
      if (this.RemoveItemCommand?.CanExecute(tabItemToRemove) ?? false)
      {
        this.RemoveItemCommand.Execute(tabItemToRemove);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ClosableTabControl}"
         BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" />

    <!-- Add a close button to the tab header -->
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
      <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                  Value="1,1,1,0" />
          <Setter Property="Margin"
                  Value="0,2,0,0" />
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DimGray" />
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                      Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    <Button Content="X"
                            Command="{x:Static local:ClosableTabControl.CloseTabRoutedCommand}"
                            Height="16"
                            Width="16"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="4" />
                  </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex"
                            Value="100" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                            Value="0,0,0,-1" />
                  </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- Provide a default DataTemplate for the tab header
         This will only work if the data item has a property Title -->
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- Provide a default DataTemplate for the tab content
         This will only work if the data item has a property Content -->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Usage Example**

```
<Window> 
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel" x:Name="MainViewModel" />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ClosableTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                      RemoveItemCommand="{Binding RemoveTabItemCommand}" />
</Window>
```

### Remarks

Instead of removing the item from the `ItemsSource` (this is what actually your requirement is) I recommend to toggle the `TabItem.Visibility` and set it to `Visibility.Collapsed` in order to remove the `TabItem` from the view. This is a more intuitive and flexible behavior (e.g., reopen recently closed). Because when the user removes it from the view it doesn't mean it has to be removed from the view model too. If the view model decides to *really* remove the data model, it can simply remove it from the binding source collection. This would also eliminate the need of the `ClosableTabControl.RemoveItemCommand` property as the `Visibility` can/must be handled inside the `ClosableTabControl`.

So `ClosableTabControl.ExecuteRemoveTab` method would become:

```
private void ExecuteRemoveTab(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  object tabItemToRemove = this.ItemsSource == null
    ? e.Source
    : (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext;

  // Select the next tab after the removed tab
  int lastItemIndex = this.Items.Count - 1;
  int nextItemIndex = this.Items.IndexOf(tabItemToRemove) + 1;
  this.SelectedIndex = Math.Min(lastItemIndex, nextItemIndex);

  (this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(tabItemToRemove) as UIElement).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

**Usage Example**

```
<Window> 
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel" x:Name="MainViewModel" />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ClosableTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}" />
</Window>
```