# Dynamically Add a User Control inside the Tab Item in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

> Hi all, I am new in WPF, My project goal is when user click the create page menuitem, it will open
> createpage(UserControl). that usercontrol have 2 textblock, 2 textbox and one button. user click the button. My another UserControl displayed in my mainwindow tabcontrol(Main window have Menubar, one stackpanel and tabcontrol.

[ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkr7w.jpg)

[ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5oXk.jpg)

[ScreenShot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyqDA.jpg)

> My Error is: After Page button clicked tab item not bind in my mainwindow tabcontrol

> My Code is below:
> MainWindow Xaml:

```
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabItemCloseProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <MenuItem Header="Page" Foreground="White" Background="DarkSlateGray" Click="Page_Click"/>
        </Menu>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TabStripPlacement="Bottom" x:Name="createpagetabcntrl">
            <TabItem Header="createpage" x:Name="createpagetab"></TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <TabControl x:Name="actionTabs" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="21" Width="100">
                        <TextBlock Width="80" Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                        <Button Content="X" Width="20" Height="20" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black"
                              Click="Closebtn" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <UserControl Height="800" Width="1220" Content="{Binding Content}" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> Main Window Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TabItemCloseProject.ViewModel;

namespace TabItemCloseProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ActionTabViewModel vmd;
        public static MainWindow mwindow;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }

        public static MainWindow Initialize()
        {
            if(mwindow==null)
            {
                mwindow = new MainWindow();
            }
            return mwindow;
        }

        private void Closebtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vmd.Tabs.RemoveAt(actionTabs.SelectedIndex);
        }

        private void Page_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            createpagetab.Content=new CreatePage();
        }
    }
}
```

> TabItem Property Stored Class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TabItemCloseProject
{
    public class ActionTabItem
    {
        // This will be the text in the tab control
        public string Header { get; set; }
        // This will be the content of the tab control It is a UserControl whits you need to create manualy
        public UserControl Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> My View Model Class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;

namespace TabItemCloseProject.ViewModel
{
    public class ActionTabViewModel
    {
        // These Are the tabs that will be bound to the TabControl 
        public ObservableCollection<ActionTabItem> Tabs { get; set; }

        public ActionTabViewModel()
        {
            Tabs = new ObservableCollection<ActionTabItem>();
        }

        public void Populate()
        {
            // Add A tab to TabControl With a specific header and Content(UserControl)
            Tabs.Add(new ActionTabItem { Header = "UserControl 1", Content = new TestUserControl() });
            // Add A tab to TabControl With a specific header and Content(UserControl)
            Tabs.Add(new ActionTabItem { Header = "UserControl 2", Content = new TestUserControl() });
        }
    }
}
```

> Create Page User Control(It will bind on when user click Page Menu item)

```
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabItemCloseProject"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="DarkSlateGray">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" Margin="10,20">PageNo</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" Margin="10,20">PageName</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Width="60" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <Button Content="OK" Background="DarkSlateGray" Height="40" Width="80"
                Click="createPage" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

> Create Page Code Behind Class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TabItemCloseProject.ViewModel;

namespace TabItemCloseProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CreatePage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CreatePage : UserControl
    {
        private ActionTabViewModel vmd;
        public CreatePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void createPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vmd = new ActionTabViewModel();
            // Bind the xaml TabControl to view model tabs
            MainWindow m = MainWindow.Initialize();
            m.actionTabs.ItemsSource = vmd.Tabs;
            // Populate the view model tabs
            vmd.Populate();
            //this.DataContext = vmd;
        }
    }
}
```

> 2nd User Control(It will bind on after creating page button clicked this user control bind on Main Window Tab Item)

```
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabItemCloseProject"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>Tab Item is worked!..</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

> 2nd User Control Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TabItemCloseProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TestUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public TestUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Normally we'd have to ask for more details and/or code. But this is the other way around. This is simply too much. You need to try and produce a minimally reproduceable example. Also your question is not entirely clear to me, but this is perhaps due to large volume of code posted.

Comment: Add Tab Item Dynamically with Close button.

Comment: 1) User Click Page Menu Item--> It will open Create Page User Control--> After Fill the User Control Info Click the Ok Button. I need to bind My Tab Item (User Control) My MainWindow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449451/how-to-add-close-button-in-tab-of-dynamic-wpf-tab-control Maybe this is what you are looking for?